# How to deploy my WCF service on IIS 6.0?

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis

I am completely new to `WCF` and deploying of services. I am having trouble setting up my service on IIS 6.0.

I need the exact steps to deploy my `WCF` service on IIS 6.0.

Note: I created a `WCF` service application...

So, what is the exact steps i need to follow to deploy my wcf service on IIS 6.0?

Comment: See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX8quq7MoeI

Comment: Or MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have basically two options, I believe:

**Option 1 - "bin" deploy** (preferred option)

1. compile your WCF service into a DLL (class library)
2. create a website in IIS6
3. copy the WCF DLL's into the website's `.\bin` folder
4. create a `*.svc` file in that website
5. add an appropriate `web.config` in the website folder to define your endpoints and service configuration etc.

Your WCF service will now be reachable at the website's base address, plus the name of the `*.svc` file, e.g.

```
http://myserver/someweb/Myservice.svc
```

Your `*.svc` would look something like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="WCF_Simple_Service.HelloIndigoService"  %>
```

The `Service=` attributes denotes the class implementing the service - fully qualified with its namespace.

**Option 2 - put stuff into `App_Code`**

1. create a website in IIS6
2. put all your WCF related `*.cs` files directly into the `.\App_Code` folder
3. create a `*.svc` file in that website
4. add an appropriate `web.config` in the website folder to define your endpoints and service configuration etc.

Your WCF service will now be reachable at the website's base address, plus the name of the `*.svc` file, e.g.

```
http://myserver/someweb/Myservice.svc
```

Your `*.svc` would look something like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="Service" 
    CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>
```

A simple, sample `web.config` might look something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WithDebug">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="SimpleWCF.HelloIndigoService" behaviorConfiguration="true">
      <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="SimpleWCF.IHelloIndigoService" />
      <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

You basically define your `<service>` tag - and again: the `name=` denotes the class implementing the service - fully qualified with its namespace. It must contain at least one endpoint - since IIS6 only support HTTP, you can use `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding` and that's about all there is. A "mex" endpoint is optional - but very useful, especially for development and testing. It allows client to "discover" the service and get its service description so it can interface with it.

Once your service is deployed in IIS, you can see it in action using a tool like the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) that ships for free with WCF, or [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) which is a general-purpose SOAP testing utility (with a free edition for you to use).

Comment: Do i need to add anything in the address tag of my first endpoint?

Comment: @Willem: typically no - when hosting in IIS, it's IIS's virtual directory that controls the address. You could add something like `MyService` to it - a "relative" address - then your service would be at `http://MyServer/VirtualDir/MyService.svc/MyService` - but since that `*.svc` file is in there anyway, those addresses get a bit clunky....