# Steps to Build and deploy a WCF Service on IIS using PowerShell scripting

Tags: wcf, iis, powershell, hosting

Can some one please help me on the Steps to build and Deploy a WCF Service on IIS using the PowerShell Scripting.

Regards,
Harshal

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460744/how-to-deploy-my-wcf-service-on-iis-6-0/9460906#9460906 it covers IIS hosting in great detail

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: I dont have the exact one but here is the good sample @ [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/an-introduction-to-windows-powershell-and-iis#02)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a PowerShell snap-in for IIS 7. You can find it here:
https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/getting-started-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in

With that snap-in, you can very easily add/configure application pools, create IIS Applications, backup the IIS config files and so on.

The "deploy" part of your question can easily be implemented by a PS script running as a postbuild event.