# Deploying local WCF service using Powershell

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, powershell

I have a wcf service with multiple endpoints which I would like to deploy locally using powershell. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Additional functionality - Only deploy specific endpoints which are outlined in a config/csv file.

Comment: Your question is somewhat open ended. There are no powershell scripts for WCF because there is  nothing special about WCF hosting. WCF is usually hosted either in a windows service or in IIS. So you should be asking how to deploy a windows service using powershell or how to deploy to IIS using powershell (see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9494349/569662)

Comment: You're right Hugh, apologies for being a little vague. It was the latter, deploying to IIS using powershell. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steps to Build and deploy a WCF Service on IIS using PowerShell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494349/steps-to-build-and-deploy-a-wcf-service-on-iis-using-powershell-scripting)