# Hosting WCF service using powershell

Tags: powershell, wcf

I have about 3 WCF services to be hosted in IIS and  2 as Windows Service in the same server.

In order to make the deployment automated, I am thinking of using Powershell which will read the configuration from a file (json, or xml) containing all the required information for the service to be hosted (type of host, port etc). And also write to log file about the steps that it executed and status of service.

Is it technically possible to do it in Powershell ? I'm sure from where to start with, and searching over internet did not give me a proper clue/direction.

Please advice with links or samples. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is possible. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494349/steps-to-build-and-deploy-a-wcf-service-on-iis-using-powershell-scripting

Comment: Thanks for the link. But that's for IIS only. Need for Windows service also

Comment: My wcf service output is .dll How do i utilize that to install a windows service using powershell ?